# Invalid command 'text/css', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, text, error-log

We're running Laravel 5.4 on Linux and Apache. The following error has suddenly been showing up in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` without changes made to our `.htaccess` file:

```
/var/www/html/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'text/css', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The entire `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

    # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

    # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

    # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

    # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"

    # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

    # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Force traffic through https
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

    # Redirect non-www urls to www
    # Force through www for SSL certificate coverage (except IP)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # End of Apache Rewrite Rules

</IfModule>

# BEGIN Compression
<IfModule mod_filter.c>

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/manifest+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/schema+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.geo+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/eot
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/cache-manifest
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vcard
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vtt
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-cross-domain-policy
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

</IfModule>
# END of Compression
```

Comment: Are you able to match this error with a request in your access log? Are you getting this error with every request for CSS files? If the `.htaccess` file was generating this error then you would expect to see a 500 (Internal Server Error) response. FWIW your `.htaccess` file "looks" OK.  (Any strange hidden chars??)

Comment: @user82217 I was able to find a request in the `access_log` matching the timestamp with a 500 error response. It does seem to have been coming from a single URI (requests all have 500 error yesterday), but has not been triggered since even though the page has been accessed. We'll be keeping an eye on it in case it comes back.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error today as well while setting up a new dev environment. After trying everything I could find I finally stumbled on an article indicating there are too many lines in the filter block. From the article:

**Symptoms**

Web site fails to open showing 500 type error.

There is a record similar to this in the /var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/error_log file:

[core:alert] /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: Invalid command 'text/css', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

**Cause**

Too long declaration of the AddOutputFilterByType expression in the .htaccess file.

Refer to the following resources for additional information:

https://github.com/ezekg/theme-juice-vm/issues/4
http://mail.blueonyx.it/pipermail/blueonyx/2010-April/004320.html

**Resolution**

Modify the  section, so it would look similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" "application/javascript" "application/json" "application/ld+json" "application/manifest+json" "application/rdf+xml" "application/rss+xml" "application/schema+json" "application/vnd.geo+json" "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" "application/x-font-ttf" "application/x-javascript" "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" "application/xhtml+xml" "application/xml" "font/eot" "font/opentype" "image/bmp" "image/svg+xml" "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" "image/x-icon" "text/cache-manifest" "text/css" "text/html" "text/javascript" "text/plain" "text/vcard" "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" "text/vtt" "text/x-component" "text/x-cross-domain-policy" "text/xml"
</IfModule>
```

It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find a matching request in the `/var/log/httpd/access_log` for each of the "Invalid command" errors:

```
[14/Jun/2017:09:11:05 -0500] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36"
```

This error has not occurred since yesterday morning even with the page being accessed after. We cleared the cache, removed all sessions and restarted the server shortly after posting the original question.